# How can I flatten an array of objects to return the exact result I need?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like so:

```
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

Then when you open each object up I have some data inside like so:

```
id: "restore-product"
result: 0
```

Currently the data is output like the above but what I would love is to be able to manipulate it so i can get the returned array of objects to look like this:

```
[[id:"restore-product",result:0],[id:"enhance-product",result:20]]
```

Then when the time comes I can loop through each item and find the highest value out of the objects and get the id of that highest value.

Currently I have this function that pushes items into the array:

```
var amounts = [];
    $.each(entries, function(i, entry){

      amounts.push(entry);

    });
```

== edit here ===

This is what i use to get the highest value:

```
var lowest = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var highest = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
var tmp;
for (var i=entries.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    tmp = entries[i].result;
    if (tmp < lowest) lowest = tmp;
    if (tmp > highest) highest = tmp;
}
console.log(highest, lowest);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The response type you're after is not possible in JS as you cannot have named parameters in an array. The best you can do is an array of objects - which is *exactly* what you already have. For what reason are you trying to change the data?

Comment: I need to be able to get the highest result out of the array and map that to the id. In simple terms get the id of the highest value in the array

Comment: Whats wrong with the output [{id: 'somesting', parameter: 'other'},{id: 'something else', parameter: 'otherrr'}] ? You can loop through all objects and manipulate all attributes

Comment: noa-dev thats what I want but not what is being outputted

Comment: Rory is right, you can't have that as you think. You have to build a function that calculates the maximum result and then get the id of that object

Comment: To get the highest valued ID, just create two variables `id` and `localMax =  Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` then for a for loop through your objects. If you find a value greater than `localMax`, update `localMax` and `id`.

Comment: @Mdunbavan Yes it is what you have, it is just printed in a confusing way to you, I guess.

Comment: seems to me you already have the data structure that you are saying you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much simpler way of finding the highest value with a matching ID. Just setup two tracker variables and update them as you move through the array.

```
var id = null;
var localMax = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
  var obj = objects[i];
  if (obj.result > localMax) {
    id = obj.id;
    localMax = obj.result;
  }
}
```

Comment: would this check through all of them and discard the ones lower and only get the highest result out of all of the objects because there will be 5 in total at all times?

Comment: @Mdunbavan Yes, this would go through all of them and only get the highest one.

Comment: with this answer is it possible to get the second highest value?

Comment: @Mdunbavan Sure. Just create a second variable (or set of variables) and assign them the values of `id` and `localMax` before updating them. It doesn't take too much thinking to come to that conclusion,

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is something like this:

```
function getIdFromMaximumResult(arr) {
  var id, maxResult = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
  $.each(arr, function(i, object) {
    if (object.result > maxResult) {
      maxResult = object.result;
      id = object.id;
    }
  });
  return id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to sort the array and take either the last (ascending sort) or first (descending sort) value from the result.

*Ascending sort*

```
var sorted = yourArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.result < b.result ? -1 : +(a.result > b.result);
    }),
    highest = sorted[sorted.length - 1];

console.log(highest.id);
```

You could also use `sorted.pop()` but note that this actually removes the item from the original array too.

*Descending sort*

```
var sorted = yourArray.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.result > b.result ? -1 : +(a.result < b.result);
    }),
    highest = sorted[0];

console.log(highest.id);
```

You could also use `sorted.shift()` but note that this actually removes the item from the original array too.

---

If you need any further action, for example get all id's whose result match the highest (if any), you can now use other array methods such as `filter`.

```
var sameResult = yourArray.filter(function(data) {
        return data.result === highest.result;
    });

console.log(sameResult);
```

If you want an array containing only the id's, use `map`

```
var idOnly = sameResult.map(function(data) {
        return data.id;
    });

console.log(idOnly);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```
var minMax = data.reduce(function(minMax, curr){
   minMax.min = curr.result < minMax.min ? curr.result : minMax.min;
   minMax.max = curr.result > minMax.max ? curr.result : minMax.max;
   return minMax;
},{min:Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER} );

console.log(minMax)// {min:0, max:323}
```